# How do you access an object's fields from a Parse query result in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The Parse documentation provides examples of queries using Swift, and they show an example accessing a built-in field like objectId or count, but what about accessing one of the columns of the object?

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "MyObject")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if !(error != nil) {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object["name"])
            }
            else {
                println("%@", error)
            }
    }
```

Gets the error "AnyObject" is not convertible to string.

```
object.objectForKey("name")
```

Also gives an error: "Could not find an overload for 'objectForKey' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Now I also tried "as PFObject" or something similar, but it also results in errors plus Parse's documentation doesn't show anything like that.  "Type '[AnyObject]' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'PFObject'; did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast?"

Then I apply the fix, the new error is "Type 'PFObject' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Tried also downcasting inside the loop with

```
let pf = object as PFObject
```

but that doesn't seem to help because when I do

```
let name = pf["name"]
```

I get "'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'"

Thanks for your help. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, since I haven't found anything yet;

Comment: have you tried `let name = pf["name"] as String` ?

Comment: That did it, thank you. So you just always have to cast things like this?
Add it as an answer below and I will select it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the attribute you are retrieving -

```
let name = pf["name"] as String
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "People")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            // query successful - display number of rows found
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) people")

            // print name & hair color of each person found
            for object in objects {

                let name = object["name"] as NSString
                let color = object["hairColor"] as NSString

                println("\(name) has \(color) hair")

            }
        } else {

            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
```